# How to use material2 data table with http rest api

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to do this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Helpers } from '../../../../../../../helpers';
import { ScriptLoaderService } from '../../../../../../../_services/script-loader.service';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Component({
    selector: ".m-grid__item.m-grid__item--fluid.m-wrapper",
    templateUrl: "./base-data-json.component.html",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})


export class BaseDataJsonComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    displayedColumns = ['ID', 'Nombres', 'Apellidos', 'Cedula'];
    exampleDatabase = new ExampleDatabase(null);
    dataSource: ExampleDataSource | null;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new ExampleDataSource(this.exampleDatabase, this.paginator);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {


    }
}

export interface Element {
    id_personal: number;
    nombres: string;
    apellidos: string;
    cedulas: number;
}

export class ExampleDatabase {
    /** Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
    dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Element[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Element[]>([]);
    get data(): Element[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

    private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/personals';
    datax: any = {};
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.getDatos();
        this.getData();

    }
    public getData() {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json())
    }

    public getDatos() {
        return this.getData().subscribe(data => {
            this.datax = data;
            console.log(this.datax);
        });
    }
}

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    constructor(private _exampleDatabase: ExampleDatabase, private _paginator: MatPaginator) {
        super();
    }

    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
        const displayDataChanges = [
            this._exampleDatabase.dataChange,
            this._paginator.page,
        ];

        return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
            const data = this._exampleDatabase.data.slice();

            // Grab the page's slice of data.
            const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
            return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
        });
    }

    disconnect() { }
}
```

**And I get this error:**

> BaseDataJsonComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'get' of null at
>   ExampleDatabase.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/theme/pages/default/components/datatables/base/base-data-json/base-data-json.component.ts.ExampleDatabase.getData
>   (base-data-json.component.ts:61) at
>   ExampleDatabase.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/theme/pages/default/components/datatables/base/base-data-json/base-data-json.component.ts.ExampleDatabase.getDatos
>   (base-data-json.component.ts:65) at new ExampleDatabase
>   (base-data-json.component.ts:56) at new BaseDataJsonComponent
>   (base-data-json.component.ts:26) at createClass (core.es5.js:10910) at
>   createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10751) at createViewNodes
>   (core.es5.js:12192) at createRootView (core.es5.js:12082) at
>   callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467) at Object.debugCreateRootView
>   [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12771)

Also tried to do it as a service, but no luck.
**What am I doing wrong???
Please help!!!**. Thanks in advance